# Copy multiple csv files to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have multiple csv files and need to copy them into one postgres database. Besides, I want to add one more column for my table which can display the name from each file. Anybody can help on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temp table with the structure of data from your `CSV` and another with the same structure and  adding the column to the name of `CSV` file, and make a `plpgsql` code to load the files into the  table,  for example:

Files:

`file1.csv`

```
hello,world21,2021
hello,world20,2020
hello,world12,2019
```

`file2.csv`

```
hello,world18,2018
hello,world17,2017
hello,world16,2016
```

Code to load csv files

```
create table csvtable (file text, hi text, world text, yr integer );

do $$
declare 
files text[]:=array['file1.csv','file2.csv'];
copy_command text;
x text;
begin 
create table csvtable_tmp ( hi text, world text, yr integer );

FOREACH x IN ARRAY files
  LOOP
    copy_command := 'copy csvtable_tmp from '''||x || '''csv delimiter '',''';
    execute copy_command;
    insert into csvtable select x,* from csvtable_tmp;
    truncate csvtable_tmp;
  END LOOP;

 drop table csvtable_tmp;
end;
$$
```

```
db=# select * from csvtable;
      file |  hi   |  world  |  yr  
-----------+-------+---------+------
 file1.csv | hello | world21 | 2021
 file1.csv | hello | world20 | 2020
 file1.csv | hello | world12 | 2019
 file2.csv | hello | world18 | 2018
 file2.csv | hello | world17 | 2017
 file2.csv | hello | world16 | 2016
(6 rows)
```